# Load root filesystem from USB device

Tags: linux, filesystems, startup, reboot, rootfs

I'm trying to make a fast reboot to the other Linux system. First step is kernel loading, I make it with
`sudo kexec --append='$(cat /proc/cmdline)' -l new_kernel.img --reuse-cmdline`
`sudo kexec -e`
It works fine, but loads only kernel, not entire system.

How can I mount an `*.img` file with OS resources, located at USB as `/`? Preferable during kernel loading, but afterwards mount is still suitable. `*.img` format is not necessary, it can be unpacked before

Comment: You want pivot_root

Comment: From man page: pivot_root() changes the root mount in the mount namespace of the calling process. But at the end there are also few words about switch_root(), which seems more suitable for my purposes

Answer (score 1):

As *stark* said, pivot root() was the call I was searching for. Commands to make a USB located at /dev/sdb1 a root directory:

```
sudo -s
mkdir /newroot
mount /dev/sdb1 /newroot
cd /newroot
mkdir oldroot
pivot_root . oldroot/
```

switch_root() deletes all files at the previous root dir, also there are few other differences, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126222/477009) might be useful